How to dispace a vdb volume using a sphere?
I would like to create a showckwave like effect using a sphere force field to repulse a vdb fog I created.
The idea is to make this effect https://youtu.be/O7hgjuFfn3A?si=56cTmPpKWgChYSyb&t=468 at 7:48.
Is there a way to do that in Blender or is it only possible using a post process effect ?
Thank you,

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
